# How can I disable bells/visualbells in vim?

Tags: vim, bell

How can I disable bells/visualbells in vim?

I've tried:

```
set noeb
set novb
```

.. but nothing has changed afaik.

Just to be clear, I'm referring to the visual bell I get in vim when I do something that doesn't do anything, for exmaple pressing `ESC` in normal mode, or pressing `h` in  on col 0.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To disable the bell altogether, you need to

- *enable* vim's internal visual bell¹, with `set visualbell` (= `set vb`);
- set the effect of the vim visual bell to do nothing, with `set t_vb=`

(This is explained in the documentation of `'visualbell'`, but not very clearly.)

¹ <sub>Even with `novisualbell`, you might see a visual bell if vim emits a bell control sequence (usually `\a`) and the terminal is configured to flash rather than make a sound.</sub>

Comment: Note that you'll have to add 'set t_vb=' to your .gvimrc as well if you're using gvim.

Comment: Actually only `:set novisualbell` helped me for `jvi` in Netbeans.