# Screen blinks when unauthorized action is attempted

Tags: terminal, bell, user-interface

I'm running Fedora 16. When I'm using vim or the terminal and I mistakenly direct the cursor to an inaccessible place, eg when the cursor is all the way to the top or left of the screen, the whole screen blinks. How can I disable this?

I really like fedora but this setting drives me nuts.

Comment: Most terminals let you choose between that screen flash and an audible bell. Some let you turn it off, so that you wouldn't depend on a per-application setting. What terminal emulator do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called "Visual Bell" - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154616/disable-visual-bell-on-centos) for how to fix it in bash.

```
set bell-style none
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that put, I didn't know that it was called visual bell.

I've entered 'set bell-style none' and bind 'set bell-style none' in the .bashrc file but it hasn't had any effect.

I've been able to turn it off in vim though, see below.

http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5310/how-can-i-disable-bells-visualbells-in-vim

Answer (score 0):

The method that worked for me under Fedora 21 was `unset LS_COLORS`,
to erase the contents of that environment variable.